# Retrieve Invoices of a Customer from SOAP API v2 WS-I

Tags: magento-1.8, api

`salesOrderInvoiceList` gives me a list of the invoices:

```
object(stdClass)[5]
  public 'complexObjectArray' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'increment_id' => string '100000001' (length=9)
          public 'created_at' => string '2014-12-02 04:05:47' (length=19)
          public 'order_currency_code' => string 'AUD' (length=3)
          public 'order_id' => string '688' (length=3)
          public 'state' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'grand_total' => string '70.0000' (length=7)
          public 'invoice_id' => string '448' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'increment_id' => string '100000002' (length=9)
          public 'created_at' => string '2014-12-02 04:08:49' (length=19)
          public 'order_currency_code' => string 'AUD' (length=3)
          public 'order_id' => string '687' (length=3)
          public 'state' => string '2' (length=1)
          public 'grand_total' => string '60.0000' (length=7)
          public 'invoice_id' => string '449' (length=3)
```

Is there a way to retrieve invoices based on the customer ID and/or email? **Do I need to [create my own API?](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Magento documentation on salesOrderInvoiceList](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderInvoice/sales_order_invoice.list.html) states that you can apply "complex filters"

Reading from the example, I think you can achieve this doing:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'customer_id',
            'value' => array('key' => 'eq', 'value' => '1234')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->salesOrderInvoiceList($session, $complexFilter);
```